How to create a new array based on an array that has been defined in Excel VBA
I defined the array as:
A = Array(20082, 20081, 20092, 20091, 20102, 20101, 20112, 20111, 20122, 20121)
I want to create a new array based on array A as:
B = Array(20092, 20091, 20102, 20101, 20112, 20111, 20122)
How to do it in VBA?
thanks for the advice
Sub CreateNewArray()
    Dim A() As Variant
    Dim NewArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' Define your original array A
    A = Array(20082, 20081, 20092, 20091, 20102, 20101, 20112, 20111, 20122, 20121)
    
    ' Initialize the index for the new array
    j = 0
    
    ' Loop through the elements of array A
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        ' Check if the element is within the desired range
        If A(i) >= 20092 And A(i) <= 20122 Then
            ' Add the element to the new array
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(j)
            NewArray(j) = A(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Print the new array (optional)
    For i = LBound(NewArray) To UBound(NewArray)
        Debug.Print NewArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Result

Expected results:
20092
20091
20102
20101
20112
20111
20122


The source array is not in order. If A(i) >= 20092 And A(i) <= 20122 Then doesn't work as your expected.

Sub CreateNewArray()
    Dim A() As Variant
    Dim NewArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    ' Define your original array A
    A = Array(20082, 20081, 20092, 20091, 20102, 20101, 20112, 20111, 20122, 20121)
    ' Initialize the index for the new array
    j = 0
    Dim bFlag As Boolean
    ' Loop through the elements of array A
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        ' Get the start and end index
        If A(i) = 20092 Then
            bFlag = True ' found start num
        ElseIf A(i) = 20122 Then
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(j)
            NewArray(j) = A(i)
            Exit For ' stop For looping
        End If
        If bFlag Then ' populate new array
            ReDim Preserve NewArray(j)
            NewArray(j) = A(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ' Print the new array (optional)
    For i = LBound(NewArray) To UBound(NewArray)
        Debug.Print NewArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub



Get the sub-array with string operation

Sub CreateNewArray()
    Dim A() As Variant
    Dim NewArray As Variant
    Const SEP = "|"
    Const STARTNUM = "20092"
    Const ENDNUM = "20122"
    ' Define your original array A
    A = Array(20082, 20081, 20092, 20091, 20102, 20101, 20112, 20111, 20122, 20121)
    Dim sTxt As String: sTxt = SEP & Join(A, SEP) & SEP
    Dim ISTART As Long, iEnd As Long
    ISTART = InStr(sTxt, SEP & STARTNUM & SEP)
    iEnd = InStr(sTxt, SEP & ENDNUM & SEP)
    If iEnd > ISTART And ISTART * iEnd > 0 Then
        NewArray = Split(Mid(sTxt, ISTART + 1, iEnd + Len(ENDNUM) - ISTART), SEP)
        ' Print the new array (optional)
        For i = LBound(NewArray) To UBound(NewArray)
            Debug.Print NewArray(i)
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't find nums."
    End If
End Sub

